# Removing duplicates from FOR statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have the following

```
var ahrefLength = $('a').length;
for (var i = 0; i < ahrefLength; i++) {
    var ahrefUrl = $('a')[i].attr('href');
    if(ahrefUrl != '') {
       $('a')[i].text('Unique');
    }
}
```

How can I fix this so that no duplicates of "href" appear ? At the moment, if 2 `href` are the same it fixes both ? i.e. I need to ensure that no duplicates

Comment: You're doing redundant DOM selection in a loop... *twice*. That's really bad. You need to cache it outside the loop.

Comment: @amnotiam - can you provide an answer with a fix ? :)

Comment: [Already did.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8845558/1106925) :)

Comment: @amnotiam whoops yeah :) can you provide a `for` statement however ?

Comment: Sure, I'll update with a `for` statement version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = {};
$('a[href]').text(function(i,text) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if( !(href in list) )
        return list[href] = 'Unique';
    else
        ; // what do you want to do with the duplicate?
});
```

---

To use a `for` statement:

```
var list = {};
var a_els = $('a[href]');  // Cache the DOM selection
var len = a_els.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var a_i = a_els.eq(i);
    var href = a_i.attr('href');
    if( !(href in list) )
        a_i.text(list[href] = 'Unique');
    else
        ; // what do you want to do with the duplicate?
}
```

Comment: great thanks :) just wondering ' what's the difference between `$('a')[i]` and `$('a').eq(i)` i.e. in terms of `$('a')[i].href` or `$('a').eq(i).attr('href')`

Comment: @Andy: `[i]` gives you the native DOM element stored in the jQuery object. It doesn't have any jQuery methods. `.eq(i)` gives you the same element, but in a jQuery object, so you can use the methods. Using `.href` gives you the value of the `.href` property, while `.attr('href')` gives you the attribute. The property will give you a fully qualified url, while the attribute will give you exactly what was sent from the server.

Comment: ...and `$('a')` searches the entire DOM for all `<a>` elements. This is an expensive operation, which is why you don't want to do it repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [an associative array (viz., an object)](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) as a sort of "set" to keep track of what URLs you've already seen:

```
var ahrefLength = $('a').length;
var hrefsToSkip = { '': true };
for (var i = 0; i < ahrefLength; i++) {
    var ahrefUrl = $('a')[i].attr('href');
    if(! hrefsToSkip[ahrefUrl]) {
       $('a')[i].text('Unique');
       hrefsToSkip[ahrefUrl] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hrefIdx = {};
var href = null;
$('a').each(function(i, e) {
  href = $(this).attr('href');
  if ( href != '' && !hrefIdx[href]) {
    $(this).text('Unique');
    hrefIdx[href] = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery slice:)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mhNra/

Remove all duplicates starting from the end

```
$( "a" ).each( function() {     
     $( "a[href=" + $( this ).attr( "href" ) + "]" ).slice( 0, -1 ).remove()
 });
```

Remove all duplicates starting from the first anchor

```
 $( "a" ).each( function() {     
     var arr = $( "a[href=" + $( this ).attr( "href" ) + "]" );
     arr.slice( 1, arr.length  ).remove()
 });
```